# Selenium - bypass ads Google_Vignette

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm trying to crawl a site and am running into a google ad. I think I've found the iframe of it but I can't find the element to click to remove the ad. I've spent about 7 hours now and think this is over my head. Help v much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path ='C:\/Users\/gblac\/OneDrive\/Desktop\/Chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://free-mp3-download.net/'
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
search = driver.find_element(By.ID,'q')
search.send_keys('testing songs')
search.click()

button = driver.find_element(By.ID,'snd')
button.click()

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'container'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"results_t")));
results = driver.find_element(By.ID,'results_t').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr')
results[0].find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').click()
# The code to remove the ad would go here 
# driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[text()="Close"]').click()
```

Comment: you can just delete the div that is being used to show the ad

Comment: add an extension like ublock origin when initializing the driver/browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code block in your code - before searching any text:

```
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("""
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("google-auto-placed");
while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
                      """)

time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("""
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle adsbygoogle-noablate");
while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
                      """)

time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"q").send_keys("tamil songs")
driver.find_element(By.ID,"snd").click()
```

It will close the 2 ad blocks in that page, but if you refresh or move forward and backward, the ads will display again, then you have to remove those ad blocks again using the above code, please add the code for that condition.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'container'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"results_t")))
results = driver.find_element(By.ID,'results_t').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr')
results[0].find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//button[contains(text(),'Download')]").click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
time.sleep(1)

# handling captcha
iframe_captcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_captcha)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".recaptcha-checkbox-border").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//button[contains(text(),'Download')]").click()
```

Comment: Ugh now I'm having trouble finding the Download button. @abisaran

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Multiple attempts, it always work

   ```
    from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
    import time

    attempt = 0
    max_attempts = 5
    while attempt < max_attempts:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.download_button")
            element.click()
            break
        except WebDriverException as e:
            print(f"Click attempt {attempt+1} failed: {e}")
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait 2 seconds before retrying
            attempt += 1
   ```
2. Increase the wait time before clicking any element